# Chromium can't print anymore and crash - 16.04

Tags: printing, chromium

For some reason, I use Chromium only to print some stuff.
So it was printing well before recently (last version, I guess).
Now, with this version: 73.0.3683.86-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 try to print make it crash. Even with empty tab.

I tried to force old version with synaptic (version 49.0.something), but it refuse due to dependency problem. (E: Erreur, pkgProblem::Resolve a généré des ruptures, ce qui a pu être causé par les paquets devant être gardés en l'état.)

Comment: In a terminal: chromium-browser 
[13332:13332:0528/200748.703530:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print with this command:

```
chromium-browser --temp-profile
```

if ok, delete your profile folder in **$HOME/.config/chromium**

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem.  Chrome was printing fine up to last update.  After recent updates, chrome browser was crashing trying to print any page, even simple text ones.  The print dialog would open, and as soon as I hit print, chrome would crash.  I tried the suggestion above of running with temp-profile, and that worked.  But deleting the profile did not fix the normal running of chrome.  I tried other suggestions of deleting all Google local data, no good.  Also tried using the browsers Settings -> Advanced -> Reset Settings to Default, and that did nothing either.  The only thing that fixed it was moving to using Google Cloud Print for my local printer.  As soon as I set my local printer up with Google Cloud Print, I didn't have any further problems printing.  You can find instructions here:  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1069693